# "Bulk Change Primary User on Device to Last Log In" Script Error

Tags: arrays, powershell, azure-powershell

I found a Script on https://github.com/svdbusse/IntuneScripts/blob/master/PrimaryUser/Set-PrimaryUserfromLastLogIn.ps1

That changes the Primary User on all devices with the Last Logged in Users. My Problem is now that there are very old, deleted Users and i get an error. i am not really good in writing in Powershell and could need someones help.

here is the code part:

```
#Get All Windows 10 Intune Managed Devices for the Tenant

$Devices = Get-Win10IntuneManagedDevice

Foreach ($Device in $Devices){

Write-Host "Device name:" $device."deviceName" -ForegroundColor Cyan

$IntuneDevicePrimaryUser = Get-IntuneDevicePrimaryUser -deviceId $Device.id

#Check if there is a Primary user set on the device already

if($IntuneDevicePrimaryUser -eq $null){

Write-Host "No Intune Primary User Id set for Intune Managed Device" $Device."deviceName" -f Red



}



else {

$PrimaryAADUser = Get-AADUser -userPrincipalName $IntuneDevicePrimaryUser

Write-Host "Intune Device Primary User:" $PrimaryAADUser.displayName



}



#Get the objectID of the last logged in user for the device, which is the last object in the list of usersLoggedOn

$LastLoggedInUser = ($Device.usersLoggedOn[-1]).userId



#Using the objectID, get the user from the Microsoft Graph for logging purposes

$User = Get-AADUser -userPrincipalName $LastLoggedInUser

#Check if the current primary user of the device is the same as the last logged in user

if($IntuneDevicePrimaryUser -notmatch $User.id){



#If the user does not match, then set the last logged in user as the new Primary User

$SetIntuneDevicePrimaryUser = Set-IntuneDevicePrimaryUser -IntuneDeviceId $Device.id -userId $User.id



if($SetIntuneDevicePrimaryUser -eq ""){



Write-Host "User"$User.displayName"set as Primary User for device '$($Device.deviceName)'..." -ForegroundColor Green



}



}



else {

#If the user is the same, then write to host that the primary user is already correct.

Write-Host "The user '$($User.displayName)' is already the Primary User on the device..." -ForegroundColor Yellow



}



Write-Host



}
```

and i am getting this error:
Response content:

```
{"error":{"code":"Request_ResourceNotFound","message":"Resource '003fb62b-8589-48dc-8685-5f853dfb300f' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are

not present.","innerError":{"date":"2021-09-09T08:52:30","request-id":"b2371be8-7b54-461c-8075-f33672483d70","client-request-id":"b2371be8-7b54-461c-8075-f33672483d70"}}

}

Get-AADUser : Request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/003fb62b-8589-48dc-8685-5f853dfb300f failed with HTTP Status NotFound Not Found

In Zeile:471 Zeichen:17

+ $User = Get-AADUser -userPrincipalName $LastLoggedInUser

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Get-AADUser
```

Because the Computer is in the Archives and the last LoggedOn User has left he Company long ago. So i am getting this error and the for each loop stops. how can i change the script to ignore it and continue with the next device?

Comment: You could try `$user = Get-AADUser -userPrincipalName $LastLoggedInUser -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and then check `if (!$user) { continue }`

Comment: Hi @Theo, thanks for your answer. Neo Treitz and me are working on the same script, the solution you provided sounded really nice but it didn't solved the error, 

`Response content: {"error":{"code":"Request_ResourceNotFound","message":"Resource '003fb62b-8589-48dc-8685-5f853dfb300f' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.","inner Error":{"date":"2021-09-09T11:38:25","request-id":"a1d26011-b0e8-417f-9e7d-637087d59eec","client-request-id":"a1d26011-b0e8-417f-9e7d-637087d59eec"}}}`

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Then try the same of `$PrimaryAADUser = Get-AADUser ..` or wrap those calls in a `try{..} catch{..}` and use `-ErrorAction Stop`

Comment: It still breaks the loop, however we are going to try with `-SilentlyContinue` :D lets see!

Comment: In that case, skip that function and do

    `try { Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$LastLoggedInUser" -Headers $authToken -Method Get -ErrorAction Stop }   catch { <# this is where you catch the error yourself #>}` instead of letting that function catch it and return only the message.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Get-Win10IntuneManagedDevice {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
        This gets information on Intune managed devices
        .DESCRIPTION
        This gets information on Intune managed devices
        .EXAMPLE
        Get-Win10IntuneManagedDevice
        .NOTES
        NAME: Get-Win10IntuneManagedDevice
    #>
    
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$deviceName
    )
    
    $graphApiVersion = "beta"
    
    try {
        if ($deviceName) {
            $Resource = "deviceManagement/managedDevices?`$filter=deviceName eq '$deviceName'"
            $uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/$graphApiVersion/$($Resource)"
            (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $authToken -Method Get).value
        } else {
            $Resource = "deviceManagement/managedDevices?`$filter=(((deviceType%20eq%20%27desktop%27)%20or%20(deviceType%20eq%20%27windowsRT%27)%20or%20(deviceType%20eq%20%27winEmbedded%27)%20or%20(deviceType%20eq%20%27surfaceHub%27)))"
            $uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/$graphApiVersion/$($Resource)"
            $DevicesResponse = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $authToken -Method Get)
            $Devices = $DevicesResponse.value
            $DevicesNextLink = $DevicesResponse."@odata.nextLink"
            while ($DevicesNextLink -ne $null) {
                $DevicesResponse = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $DevicesNextLink -Headers $authToken -Method Get)
                $DevicesNextLink = $DevicesResponse."@odata.nextLink"
                $Devices += $DevicesResponse.value
           }
            return $Devices
        }
    } catch {
        $ex = $_.Exception
        $errorResponse = $ex.Response.GetResponseStream()
        $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($errorResponse)
        $reader.BaseStream.Position = 0
        $reader.DiscardBufferedData()
        $responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd();
        Write-Host "Response content:`n$responseBody" -f Red
        Write-Error "Request to $Uri failed with HTTP Status $($ex.Response.StatusCode) $($ex.Response.StatusDescription)"
        throw "Get-IntuneManagedDevices error"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an edited function from the same script.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.